# find form instance from other class

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have Main form with list of data inside listBox. On button click I'm opening new form to create new data object (Main form is inactive in background), when new data is submitted listobox inside main form should be populated with that new object.

I was thinking following:

1. When Form2 is submitted I was thinking to find MainForm instance and kill that instance and after that it should be easy, load again list of data from the db and display in the listbox.

Question is:

If Form1 is created and on some event Form2 is instantiated with showDialog so Form1 is inactive until data is submitted how to find Form1 instance before Form2 is closed?

So again, how to find instance of Form1 class from Form2 class?

Thanks

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can get a reference to any of the application's currently open forms by using the `Application.OpenForms` property. `Forms` in this `FormCollection` can be accessed by index like so:

```
var form1 = Application.OpenForms[0];
```

or by the form's `Name` property like so:

```
Form form1 = Application.OpenForms["Form1"];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: What if the forms are dynamically created?

Answer (score 0):

After getting the instance of an open form, I needed to call a method from that form, so this worked for me:

```
if (System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms["Form1"] != null)
 { 
     Form1 form1 = Application.OpenForms["Form1"] as Form1;
     form1.yourMethodCall();
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

if you call

```
Form1.ShowDialog(this)
```

then you'll be able to get a reference to the calling form with

```
this.Owner.Name
```

in the second form (Form2 in your case)

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog.aspx

Comment: whatever your calling form is, call ShowDialog() with the calling form as the owner